# LocalStorage for current div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make localstorage to store the current chosen div like button clicked, but I'm still weak on js coding. Could you please tell me, why this code is not working and storing the current div?

```js
$('.tdnn').click(function () {
  $("body").toggleClass('light');
  $(".moon").toggleClass('sun');
  $(".tdnn").toggleClass('day');
});



var save_button = document.getElementsByClassName('.light')
save_button.onclick = saveData;

function saveData(){
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".light");
  var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".sun");

  localStorage.setItem("save", input.value);
  var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("save");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --darkbg:#251D29;
  --darkt: #FFD1F7;
  --lightbg: #fff;
  --lightt: #D43370;
  
  --toggleHeight: 16em;
  --toggleWidth: 30em;
  --toggleBtnRadius: 10em;

  --bgColor--night: #423966;
  --toggleBtn-bgColor--night: var(--bgColor--night);
  --mooncolor: #D9FBFF;
  --bgColor--day: #9ee3fb;
  --toggleBtn-bgColor--day: var(--bgColor--day);
}

body{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  background: var(--darkbg);
  color: var(--darkt);
  text-align: center;
}
.light{
  background: var(--lightbg);
  color: var(--lightt);
}
.tdnn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*change size of toggle with font-size*/
  font-size: 30%;
  margin-top: 10em;
   position: relative;
    height: var(--toggleHeight);
    width: var(--toggleWidth);
    border-radius: var(--toggleHeight);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  background: var(--bgColor--night);
}
.day{
  background: #FFBF71;
}
.moon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  
  top: 3em;
  left: 3em;
  transform: rotate(-75deg);
  width: var(--toggleBtnRadius);
  height: var(--toggleBtnRadius);
  background: var(--bgColor--night);
  box-shadow: 
    3em 2.5em 0 0em var(--mooncolor) inset,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0em -7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 3em 7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 2em 13em 0 -4em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 6em 2em 0 -4.1em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 8em 8em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 6em 13em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) -4em 7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) -1em 10em 0 -4.5em;
}
.sun {
  top: 4.5em;
  left: 18em;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3em 3em 0 5em #fff inset,
    0 -5em 0 -2.7em #fff,
    3.5em -3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    5em 0 0 -2.7em #fff,
    3.5em 3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    0 5em 0 -2.7em #fff,
    -3.5em 3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    -5em 0 0 -2.7em #fff,
    -3.5em -3.5em 0 -3em #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    moon & sun
      <div class="tdnn">
           <div class="moon">
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

the script i wrote had to choose first the class ".light" as initial option, then when ".sun" class background is choosen the background will change and then save to "save" storage when user refresh or come back to site later.

Comment: does any value is set to localStorage?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, not a single one. So you'd need loop through each.

Comment: You're also defining the `input` variable twice

Comment: no. 1 you're trying to get a value from an Html-Collection not the element. you can get the value by simply adding '[0]' to select the first entry in that collection (`input[0].value`). no. 2 youre redefining the 'input' variable, which means you only get elements containing the '.sun' class

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('.light')` should be not dot - `document.getElementsByClassName('light')`. And use loop, or `document.getElementsByClassName('light')[0]`. 0 - number of array elements.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov there is no such thing as element with tag `light`. `.light` was correct in their code, except it's not correct way of using it...

Comment: there were many misunderstand and mistakes in my code. first to set an initial value to storage, then use loops as well.
thanks to you all for helping. I'm trying my best for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns list of elements, not a single element
2. `.light` class only available when you click the button, so your `onclick` registration will never succeed
3. you don't have anything in the code to set theme when page loaded.

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgr1b97d/

```js
if (Boolean(~~localStorage.getItem("save")))
    setTheme();

function setTheme()
{
  $("body").toggleClass('light');
  $(".moon").toggleClass('sun');
  $(".tdnn").toggleClass('day');
}

$('.tdnn').click(function()
{
  setTheme();
  saveData();
});

function saveData(){
  localStorage.setItem("save", ~~document.body.classList.contains("light"));
}
```

```css
:root {
  --darkbg:#251D29;
  --darkt: #FFD1F7;
  --lightbg: #fff;
  --lightt: #D43370;
  
  --toggleHeight: 16em;
  --toggleWidth: 30em;
  --toggleBtnRadius: 10em;

  --bgColor--night: #423966;
  --toggleBtn-bgColor--night: var(--bgColor--night);
  --mooncolor: #D9FBFF;
  --bgColor--day: #9ee3fb;
  --toggleBtn-bgColor--day: var(--bgColor--day);
}

body{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  background: var(--darkbg);
  color: var(--darkt);
  text-align: center;
}
.light{
  background: var(--lightbg);
  color: var(--lightt);
}
.tdnn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*change size of toggle with font-size*/
  font-size: 30%;
  margin-top: 10em;
   position: relative;
    height: var(--toggleHeight);
    width: var(--toggleWidth);
    border-radius: var(--toggleHeight);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  background: var(--bgColor--night);
}
.day{
  background: #FFBF71;
}
.moon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  
  top: 3em;
  left: 3em;
  transform: rotate(-75deg);
  width: var(--toggleBtnRadius);
  height: var(--toggleBtnRadius);
  background: var(--bgColor--night);
  box-shadow: 
    3em 2.5em 0 0em var(--mooncolor) inset,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0em -7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 3em 7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 2em 13em 0 -4em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 6em 2em 0 -4.1em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 8em 8em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 6em 13em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) -4em 7em 0 -4.5em,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) -1em 10em 0 -4.5em;
}
.sun {
  top: 4.5em;
  left: 18em;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3em 3em 0 5em #fff inset,
    0 -5em 0 -2.7em #fff,
    3.5em -3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    5em 0 0 -2.7em #fff,
    3.5em 3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    0 5em 0 -2.7em #fff,
    -3.5em 3.5em 0 -3em #fff,
    -5em 0 0 -2.7em #fff,
    -3.5em -3.5em 0 -3em #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    moon & sun
      <div class="tdnn">
           <div class="moon">
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works fine and code is simple to understand. Thanks man you saved my last feature on my website.